# .htaccess Internal server error issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am getting Internal Server Error when I try to open my site (http://olikez.cf/).

Below are some lines in my .htaccess file when I remove them site works but with some script error.

Lines:

```
php_flag display_errors 0
php_value error_reporting 7
php_value register_globals 0
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_value magic_quotes_runtime 0
php_value magic_quotes_sybase 0
php_value allow_url_fopen 0
php_value arg_separator.output "&amp;"
```

And below I am sharing full .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 402 http://yoursite.com/?err&404
ErrorDocument 403 http://yoursite.com/?err&403
ErrorDocument 404 http://yoursite.com/?err&404
ErrorDocument 500 http://yoursite.com/?err&500
DirectoryIndex index.php

RemoveHandler .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .py
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .py

php_flag display_errors 0
php_value error_reporting 7
php_value register_globals 0
php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_value magic_quotes_runtime 0
php_value magic_quotes_sybase 0
php_value allow_url_fopen 0
php_value arg_separator.output "&amp;"
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A1209600
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^site/([a-z0-9-_\/]+)\.([a-z0-9]{2,4}+)$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/site/$1.$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^site/([a-z0-9-_\/]+)$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/site/$1/index.html [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^site$ /site/index.html [R]
RewriteRule ^site/$ /site/index.html [R]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/index/page/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(home|index)\.html$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/index [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^captcha\.png$ captcha.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/category/category/$1/page/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/tag/tag/$1/page/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.html$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/read/post/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^content/([a-z0-9-]{1,30}+)\.([a-z0-9]{2,4}+)$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/content/filename/$1/fileext/$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rss\.xml$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/rss [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^comment/rss\.xml$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/rss/mod/comments [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/rss\.xml$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/rss/mod/post_comments/permalink/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^userlogin$ login.php?routes=/__site/true/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^usersignout$ index.php?routes=/__site/true/act/usersignout [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
RewriteCond %{HTTP:range} !(^bytes=[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,4}$|^$)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @TZHX Internal Server Error

Comment: He meant: what is reported in the error log file.

Comment: @arkascha ../public_html/olikez.cf/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: So there you have all the information you need, right?

Comment: @arkascha i am newbie and i dont know much about this errors. hope you will answer this.

Comment: Well, the error obviously shows that `php_flag` is not available in your environment. The reason can be several, but most likely php is executed as CGI on your system. https://support.tigertech.net/php-value - Do you have access to the real http server configuration, since you say it is your site? In that case you should _always_ prefer that over .htaccess style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and really slow the server down.

Comment: @arkascha thanks i am trying to change settings in php.ini file.

Comment: OK, so you _have_ access to the configuration. In that case you should be able to move all details into either the php configuration or the http host configuration. Then you can completely disable the interpretation of .htaccess style files. Only expection: if your application has to maintain a dynamic set of rules, some CMS systems do that.

Comment: Oh: and don't forget to restart the http server after making changes to either configuration. Yes, annoying, but the result without .htaccess is faster, more reliable and far easier to debug. Also note that you have to slightly adjust rewriting rules to place them in the host configuration. but you will see: it is easier to understand afterwards.

Comment: I see you fixed it. What helped?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **On/Off** for php_flag, not 0. It's different from php function display_errors(0). Replace with:

```
 php_flag display_errors Off
```

Check if you have **index.php** file on your server.

Comment: Do you have index.php on your server at all? Also, are you trying to redirect to 'yoursite.com' or to http://olikez.cf/ in case of error?